# How to remove the input string from the list?

Tags: c#

Here is my code.The first and third points of the program work properly, but the second does not.
If you press the "2" key, the data from the text should be transferred to the list, and the entered line should be deleted in the list,but for reasons I do not understand, the program crashes when entering a value into a string.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String line;
        List<String> list = new List<String>();
        String writePath = @"C:\Work\X\hta.txt";
        for (; ; )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1.Add An Employee");
            Console.WriteLine("2.Delete An Employee");
            Console.WriteLine("3.Save Database");
            Console.WriteLine("4.Exit");
            int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (choice == 4)
            {
                break;
            }
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    for (; ; )
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("1.Add A Manager");
                        Console.WriteLine("2.Add An Engineer");
                        Console.WriteLine("3.Exit");
                        int choice1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (choice1 == 3)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        switch (choice)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                line = Console.ReadLine();
                                list.Add(line);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                line = Console.ReadLine();
                                list.Add(line);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    list.Clear();
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(writePath))
                   {
                        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            list.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                        }
                    }
                   foreach(var item1 in list)
                   {
                       String linex = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (item1.Equals(linex))
                        {
                            list.Remove(linex);
                        }
                   }
                   break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue?");
                    String x = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (x.Equals("yes")){
                       using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(writePath))
                        {
                                foreach (var item in list)
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you say "the program crashes" - presumably with an exception? Please show the details of the exception in your question. Additionally, there's some odd formatting going on in the code - please get your IDE to reformat the code consistently, then edit the reformatted code into the question so that it's easier to read. (It would also help if you'd reduce this to a [mcve], although it's already *reasonably* good.)

Comment: I will advice for using some function/method. And not having everything in the same block of code. Single responsability method  will ease the testing. I will also introduce [`File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines), [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines), [`File.WriteAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines) methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop:

```
   foreach(var item1 in list)
   {
       String linex = Console.ReadLine();
        if (item1.Equals(linex))
        {
            list.Remove(linex);
        }
   }
```

You are reading input from the console for every item in the list. This would possibly look like a crash or not quite infinite loop as it's probably not what you're expecting. Instead you should read the input once then loop around the list. However, you should note that if you remove an item from the list while looping through it, you may also get strange behavior. Try just removing the string without the loop:

```
   String linex = Console.ReadLine();
   if (list.Contains(linex))
   {
       list.Remove(linex);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you writePath of value [C:\Work\X\hta.txt] file do not exists,so you should create an empty text file on you disk.